# Good question with accepted answer disappeared?

Tags: support

First off, this was a question I answered. And in in my humble opinion it was a good question that dealt with improper DNS name server settings being set on a domain registration, how to diagnose, how to resolve and the cause. A Google Cached version of the [question and answer thread exists here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:AVopncQe99IJ:superuser.com/questions/849225/domain-dns-propagation-and-resolution-issue%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari).

I provided a detailed answer and it solved the user’s problem and it was accepted.  Then shortly afterwards, it disappeared. The original Super User URL was this:

```
http://superuser.com/questions/849225/domain-dns-propagation-and-resolution-issue
```

And the page now reads:

> Page Not Found
>
> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

I will state there was a slightly headache inducing comment thread connected to my answer and why the issue came up to begin with that ended with my stating something along the lines of, “I really cannot speak for what you did in your control panel, but all I know is what you think you did actually did not work and the solution provided shows how that did not work and how I was able to deduce the issue and resolve it for you.”

I did flag moderator attention for the comment thread asking a mod simply clean that up since it was going nowhere; the problem was the problem and the problem was solved. But why then would a moderator nuke the whole thread?

So why is the question and accepted answer now gone? Can a user delete their own question when there is at least one answer? It’s my understanding that a question cannot be deleted if at least one answer is posted let alone one accepted answer.

Screenshot of the question below:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of the accepted answer:

[image]

Finally here is the comment from the original poster clearly indicating their appreciation for the answer:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the OP themselves who deleted the question. The OP can delete a question as long as it is not answered, where "answered" means that there is an accepted answer or at least one answer with a positive net score.

It's interesting that the post history does not show whether your answer was accepted, or that it was unaccepted, for that matter.

I undeleted the post and migrated it to Webmasters, where it's better suited.